# get the value of another table in a DropDownList in asp.net-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

so I have 3 table(a example):
 Dispositivos{idDisp, DispName} that has a relationship with 
Configuracion{idConfig, Configname, FK_idDispotivio} which (Configuracion) has a relationship with 
Periferico{idPeriferico , name, FK_idConfiguracion}

so what Iam trying to achieve is in my view where I create a Periferico in my DropDownList for my FK_idConfiguracion field I wanna get the Dispositivo.DispName to show in my view to the user (is just a practical example for I want. for you can undestand more easily )

I thought can do this way but can't get an error saying that configuracion dont have DispName, so how can get the DipsName to show that in my DropDownList in my periferico view?

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.Configuracion_IdConfiguracion = new SelectList(db.Configuracion.Include("Dispositivo"), "idConfig", "DispName");
```

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Configuracion_IdConfiguracion")           
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a new query to do this:

```
var items = from c in db.Configuracion
            select new { Id = c.idConfig, Display = c.Dispositivo.DispName };
```

Then you could use that to feed your dropdown list:

```
ViewBag.Configuracion_IdConfiguracion = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Display");
```

Comment: yes thank you, what you did it work. But I thought that with the navigation properties of the oject and linq to objet it will do it in a simple way

Comment: The SelectList has is not going to navigate all of your navigation properties to figure out which one has the property you are specifying.